# How to generate a Java tink key?

Tags: java, cryptography, tink

I'm using the Google Tink library in my Java project to encrypt two texts, one with Symmetric Key Encryption (SKE), and another one with Deterministic symmetric key encryption (DSKE).

This is a backend application, and I do not have a remote storage for storing a master key (google could, aws, ...).

What would be the correct way to generate the secret material that I need to encrypt both of these files ? I think I need to use 'tinkey' for this task, but I don't really understand the difference between a key and a keyset.
Can my SKE key and DSKE key be in the same keyset ? How to generate them ? Can I have a master key that's used for key rotation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to generate two keysets, one AEAD and another Deterministic AEAD.

```
tinkey create-keyset --key-template AES128_GCM --out aead-keyset.json
tinkey create-keyset --key-template AES256_SIV --out deterministic-aead-keyset.json
```

You want to store the keyset files in a secure location in your backend server. Do not commit them to your git server.

In Java, you can load the keysets using `CleartextKeysetHandle` or equivalent APIs in other languages. See the language's HOWTO for more information.